# Как организовать в БД иерархию документов?

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных

Как правильно организовать иерархию между разными документами в БД, при этом чтобы БД была в 3НФ?
Задача: Есть документ типа "Заявка" - к этому документу в будущем будут прикреплены (за счет иерархии) документы других типов, например акты, соглашения.

Я нарисовал схему такой БД (как я это понимаю). Все верно отобразил, согласно задаче?
[image: Измененная схема]

Comment: Обычное дерево. Обычный self-reference типа parent-child. *Я нарисовал схему такой БД (как я это понимаю). Все верно отобразил, согласно задаче?* Вряд ли. Сразу бросается в глаза то, что шаблон связан с документом - это явная ошибка, шаблон должен быть вообще ни с чем не связан. Остальное не смотрел...

Comment: @Akina: Изменил связи в таблицах.
По задумке, есть несколько шаблонов документов, которые должны заполняться и сохраняться в системе. Соответственно, шаблон должен быть связан через ID с определенным видом документа.

А вообще дилемма в том, что связь сущности "Документ" с самим собой создает рекурсию из-за чего не получается нормализовать БД к 3НФ. Так как сейчас организовал взаимосвязь документов через таблицу Ссылки будет решением проблемы?

Comment: *Соответственно, шаблон должен быть связан через ID с определенным видом документа.* Бред. Если шаблон изменится - что, все старые документы изменятся? а если в них нет данных, которые в новом шаблоне обязательны - документ станет невалидным? По-моему, я выразился однозначно - ШАБЛОН ДОЛЖЕН БЫТЬ ВООБЩЕ НИ С ЧЕМ НЕ СВЯЗАН. Шаблон - это сущность, а документ - это экземпляр сущности, причём совсем другой сущности, связи между ними не может быть даже теоретически. При создании нового документа шаблон КОПИРУЕТСЯ в таблицу документов, при этом создаётся экземпляр ДРУГОЙ сущности.